# What's up with the spacing between letters inside $...$?

Tags: math-mode, letterspacing

When I write `$VSS$` in my LaTeX studio, it behaves it as if there is a space between V and S (i.e. V SS).

Is there a way to fix this? I tried `\scalebox{.85}[1.0]{$VSS$}`, but it did not work well. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: For sure this is the right way to type `VSS`. Don't worry.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129400/multiple-letters-without-spacing-in-math?rq=1 and linked questions may be of interest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$VSS$` means `$V$` times `$S$` times `$S$`. If you need an italic text in math mode, you may use `$\textit{VSS}$` or `$\mathit{VSS}` (they are not equivalent).

Comment: But the default font for math is italic isn't?

Comment: @Sigur Not exactly. It is math italic, a bit wider.

Comment: @Sigur It's *math italic*; in well designed fonts it's not the same as text italic.

Comment: The difference is only spacing, right? The char shapes are the same?

Comment: Thank you very much! This solves my problem. (I cannot accept or vote up your answer because I still don't have 15 reputation.)

Comment: @Sigur more like similar.

Comment: @Sigur No. The characters are wider.

Comment: The characters are wider in the case of Computer Modern or Latin Modern or maybe some other fonts specifically designed for that. As far as I know, the math italic from MinionPro, for instance,  has the same characters as the text font, the difference is in the bounding box