# Modify/Remove italic correction in math

Tags: math-mode, spacing, italic-correction

Is there any way to modify or remove the italic correction in all math environments globally? I don't like the uneven spacing it causes when there are multiple variables multiplied together or multiple points in the same polygon, but I don't want to keep having to use "\mathit". I've looked at a number of questions here such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6089/54601 but couldn't find any that explains how to redefine the italic correction, and I don't know much about LaTeX to be able to do it myself.

Comment: That's not an italic correction. Italic corrections are extra kerning after switching from an italicized/slanted font to an upright one, such as in this *non*italic-corrected text (between `n` and `i` here you see that this software does not perform italic corrections). But anyway, don't do what you're proposing. If you remove the normal math spacing, how will you distinguish between variables multiplied together and a single multi-letter identifier/variable?

Comment: @PaulGessler: According to the comments on the answer I linked, the extra space is indeed based on the italic correction whether it's called that or not. Also I can use explicit operators such as `$\cdot$` or `$\times$` for multiplication and I see no reason I have to keep using `\mathit` for every single polygon.

Comment: If you really must do it, you can refer to the answers (not the accepted one though) at [Multiple letters without spacing in Math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129400/multiple-letters-without-spacing-in-math). And in reading the answers there you might discover that the comments you're referring to are not entirely correct.

Comment: @PaulGessler: If you mean the "deadly slow" method, no thanks haha! As for whether it is italic correction, I've no idea then.

Comment: since the "extra spacing" is the result of tex applying the font metrics, the most direct way to avoid it is to modify the metrics.  this is possible, by converting the `.tfm` file to `.pl`, modifying, and then reconverting to `.tfm`, but highly inadvisable, since it will make a lot of things no longer work correctly.