# \f@family in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I am using [this answer on TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129454/5699) to get multi-letter variables in math mode, so that `$abc$` typesets as `$\mathit{abc}$`, instead of being typeset as if it was the product of `a`, `b` and `c`.

Unfortunately, that code forces the `\mathit` even if another math font command was used, i.e. `$\mathtt{abc}$` typesets as `$\mathtt{\mathit{abc}}$`. My goal is therefore to detect what is the current font, and apply `\mathit` to multi-letter variables only if the default math font is used.

I tried using `\f@family` as shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14382), but it does not seem to work in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showfont}{
  \message{encoding: \f@encoding,
    family: \f@family,
    series: \f@series,
    shape: \f@shape,
    size: \f@size
  }
}
\makeatother

$foo \showfont bar$
$\mathtt{foo \showfont bar}$

\end{document}
```

The file above shows in the log:

```
encoding: OT1, family: cmr, series: m, shape: n, size: 10
encoding: OT1, family: cmr, series: m, shape: n, size: 10
```

It seems to me that `\f@family` and the other `\f@xxx` commands show the text mode font, instead of showing the math mode font.

Is there an equivalent to `\f@family` which gives the information concerning the math mode font?

Comment: Commands like `\mathit` and `\mathtt` don't have cumulative effect and the font parameters such as `\f@family` have no role in math mode.

Comment: @egreg I'm not trying to get a cummulative effect (italics teletype, if that's what you meant). I just want to detect the current math font, to disable the implicit `\mathit` when the current font is not the default one. As you said, `\f@family` is not supposed to work in math mode, but is there a similar command which would give me information about the current math mode font?

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron not a command a number `\the\fam` as I set to 4 actually in my answer to make things default to mathit, however the number allocation is dynamic it depends on the order that fonts are used in the document, as there are only 16 slots so if for example you declare `\mathbb` but never use it that font is never allocated a familiy number at all, they are just set up the first time they are used, which is why in my answer I use `\mathit` first to get the number and then set that for the rest of the expression.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh I see, sorry I hadn't noticed the use of `\the\fam`. I should be able to build what I want with this and the other TeX.SX answer. Thanks!

Comment: if you get something working feel free to self answer and accept (gets this off the list of unanswered questions:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added the compound solution as an answer. Could you copy/move your comment above to your answer, so that I mark it as accepted? It answers more precisely the current question title, namely "how to get \f@family in math mode?".

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron done:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a command, a number: `\the\fam` as I set to 4 actually in my answer below to make things default to `\mathit`. However the number allocation is dynamic: it depends on the order that fonts are used in the document, as there are only 16 slots (in classic TeX) so if for example you declare `\mathbb` but never use it that font is never allocated a family number at all, they are just set up the first time they are used. In the code below I use `\mathit` first to get the number and then set that for the rest of the expression.

---

You are looking at the text font settings which are not used here, you just want to set the default family to that of `\mathit`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}




$ffoo  bar$
$ffoo \mathtt{ffoo  bar} bar$

\everymath{\mathit{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam}\aftergroup\tmp}}\sbox0{$$}


$ffoo  bar$
$ffoo \mathtt{ffoo  bar} bar$


\end{document}
```

Comment: No, single letter should not be in `\mathit`, only runs of them.

Comment: @egreg hmph, then use markup to distinguish the cases, that's the point of a markup language;-)

Comment: Exactly my answer to the linked question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the answer. Like egreg mentioned, single-letter variables should still be typeset as multiplication, i.e. `$a f f b$` should not be altered. I'd like to avoid markup, otherwise I need to write `\mathit` constantly, and regularly forget it. [The answer I linked to](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129454/5699) solves that problem, and I'm just trying to disable that behaviour within an explicit `\mathtt`, `\mathrm` etc. So far, the only solution I see is to override the `\mathit`, `\mathtt` etc. commands with versions which set a flag while expanding their body.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334625/5699) to and [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334623/ffamily-in-math-mode?noredirect=1#comment820986_334623), I built a solution for my original problem using `\the\fam` to detect the current math font, based on [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129454/5699):

[image: Screenshot of the result. Multi-letter variables are implicitly typeset in red with <code>\mathit</code>, unless they are within an explicit <code>\mathit</code> or <code>\mathtt</code> etc. in which case they are typeset in blue without changing the font. Single-letter variables are typeset in blue, without changing the font.]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{etexcmds}
\newtoks\m@toks@math
\newtoks\m@toks@text

\edef\m@tmp@restore{%
  \lccode\number`\X=\the\lccode`\X\relax
  \lccode\number`\~=\the\lccode`\~\relax
}

\newcommand*{\m@activate}{}
\newcommand*{\m@check@letter}{}
\newcommand*{\m@check@fi}{}

\newif\ifm@single

\let\m@start\relax
\def\m@loop{%
  \lccode`\X=\count@
  \lccode`\~=\count@
  \lowercase{%
    \expandafter\mathchardef\csname m@code@X\endcsname=\mathcode\count@
    \edef\m@activate{%
      \etex@unexpanded\expandafter{\m@activate}%
      \mathcode\the\count@="8000\relax
      \def\noexpand~{\m@start\csname m@code@X\endcsname X}%
    }%
    \g@addto@macro\m@check@letter{%
      \ifx\@let@token X\else
    }%
  }%
  \g@addto@macro\m@check@fi{\fi}%
  \advance\count@\@ne
}
% A-Z
\count@=`\A\relax
\@whilenum\count@<\numexpr`\Z+1\relax\do{\m@loop}
% a-z
\count@=`\a\relax
\@whilenum\count@<\numexpr`\z+1\relax\do{\m@loop}

\newcommand*{\m@start}[2]{%
  \bgroup
  \m@toks@math{#1}%
  \m@toks@text{#2}%
  \m@singletrue
  \futurelet\@let@token\m@check
}
\edef\m@check{%
  \etex@unexpanded{%
    \let\m@next\m@add
    \ifx\@let@token\space
      \let\m@next\m@finish
    \else
      \ifx\@let@token\egroup
        \let\m@next\m@finish
      \else
  }%
  \etex@unexpanded\expandafter{%
        \m@check@letter
  }%
  \etex@unexpanded{%
          \let\m@next\m@finish
  }%
  \etex@unexpanded\expandafter{%
        \m@check@fi
  }%
  \etex@unexpanded{%
      \fi
    \fi
    \m@next
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\m@add}[1]{%
  \m@singlefalse
  \m@toks@math\expandafter{%
    \the\expandafter\m@toks@math
    \csname m@code@#1\endcsname
  }%
  \m@toks@text\expandafter{%
    \the\m@toks@text
    #1%
  }%
  \futurelet\@let@token\m@check
}

\newcommand*{\m@finish}{%
  \ifm@single
    \expandafter\mprintsingle\expandafter{%
      \the\expandafter\m@toks@math\expandafter
    }\expandafter{%
      \the\expandafter\m@toks@text\expandafter
    }%
  \else
    \expandafter\mprintmulti\expandafter{%
      \the\expandafter\m@toks@math\expandafter
    }\expandafter{%
      \the\expandafter\m@toks@text\expandafter
    }%
  \fi
  \egroup
}

% \let\mprintsingle\@firstoftwo
% \let\mprintmulti\@firstoftwo
\def\mprintsingle#1#2{{\color{blue}#1}}%
\def\mprintmulti#1#2{%
  % Test whether we are using the default math font or not:
  \ifnum\the\fam=-1\relax%
  \mathit{\color{red}#1}%
  \else%
  {\color{green!50!black}#1}%
  \fi%
}

\everymath{\m@activate}
\everydisplay{\m@activate}

\m@tmp@restore
\makeatother

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amstext}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{blue}{Single letters are set in blue},
\textcolor{red}{multiple letters in red},
\textcolor{green!50!black}{multiple letters inside \texttt{\textbackslash mathtt}
 or \texttt{\textbackslash mathit} etc. in green}.

\[ F_{force (implicit\ mathit)} = m_\mathit{mass (explicit\ mathit)} * a_\mathtt{acceleration (explicit\ mathtt)} \]

Multiplication of single-letter variables
\[a f f b\]

Multiplication of multi-letter variables
\[aaa fff fff bbb\]

\end{document}
```