# Kerning after variable names with multiple letters

Tags: math-mode, kerning

This question is related to [Two letter variable names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6087/) and [Multiple letters without spacing in Math [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129400/), but it seems to me that the answers to these questions do not fully solve my problem.

In the example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\par (1) $\left\{ S, Y, Z \right\}$
\par (2) $\left\{ Satz, Y, Z \right\}$
\par (3) $\left\{ \text{\textit{Satz}}, \text{\textit{Y}}, \text{\textit{Z}} \right\}$
\par (4) $\left\{ \mathit{Satz}, \mathit{Y}, \mathit{Z} \right\}$

\end{document}
```

the result

[image: Output of the MWE]

of (3) `\text{\textit{Satz}}` and (4) `\mathit{Satz}` is satisfactory with respect to the inter-word spacing of the letters. In (1) and (2), however, the spacing between `Y` and `,` looks better. Is there a way to combine both advantages without the need for manual kerning?

Please note that, although `Y` is a single-letter variable name, similar problems would arise if a multi-letter variable name ended with `Y`.

Comment: Use `$\left\{ \mathit{Satz}, Y, Z \right\}$` and avoid to many multiletter variables. Even if it works more or less with \mathit, it is confusing and -- as you see -- the spacing is not really adapted to them.

Comment: Replace with `\{\mathit{SatZ}, Z,Y\}` and you'll see this is only an optical illusion.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Multi-letter variable names cannot be fully avoided when dealing with formal grammars in theoritical informatics. There could be a case such as `SatzY` in which your advice would not help.

Comment: Then you will have to add negative space.

Comment: @Bernard I do not quite understand your above comment. Do you say that the different spacing between `Y` and `,` in the options (2) and (3) is an optical illusion? Based on a measuring the distance in the image I do not think so.

Comment: @Matthias: No, I meant between (3) and (4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \var { m }
 {
  \tl_if_single:nTF { #1 }
   { #1          }
   { \mathit{#1} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Whatever you do, *use a command*. And then you will be able to change the definition at the end even to get particular meanings (this is easily done with `\str_case:nn`).

Comment: This is a perfect solution. In real world I already have a command for variables that occur in formal grammars which I decided to omit in the MWE. However I have not had the obvious idea of an if statement. In the F branch of your if statement I can easily introduce specific kernings depending on the last letter of the variable name.

Comment: Better than that, I think would be if you introduced each case that required particular treatment, `\str_case:nnF {#1} { { Y } { <whatever> } { Z } { <whatother> } { SatZ } { <\mathit{SatZ} \kern5pt etc.> } } { \tl_if_single:nTF {#1} { #1 } { \mathit{#1} } }` that way you have many particular cases, and in case nothing matches, you get the general “do nothing” in case of single letter, or “apply `\mathit`” in case of multiple letter.